# How do I convert std::string to char Whatever[]?

Tags: c++, string, char, createfile, writefile

I'm trying to convert a simple std::string to char Whatever[]

Here is what I want to do:
Download bin2hex (file content, with \x in front) from my server to a string, convert this string to a char Whatever[] and finally write the hex to a binary file in my temp folder.

My Code:

```
        string sFileData = Utils::HTTP::POST( "http://my.url/GetBin2HexFromFile.php", _postdata, _header ).c_str( );

        char szHexData[ ] = "\x00\x00\x00\x00"; /* this should be sFileData */

        // definitions
        HANDLE hFile;
        DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
        TCHAR szPath[ MAX_PATH ] = "MyTempFile.bin";

        // create file
        hFile = CreateFileA( szPath,
                            GENERIC_WRITE,
                            0,
                            nullptr,
                            CREATE_NEW,
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                             nullptr );

        // write file
        WriteFile( hFile, szHexData, sizeof( szHexData ) - 1, &dwBytesWritten, nullptr );

        // close file handle
        CloseHandle( hFile );
```

Comment: Typically the raw `char` data is accessed through the `data()` function on the `std::string` object: `WriteFile(sFileData.data(), sFileData.size(), ...etc);`

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm stucking at /* this should be sFileData */. It gives me an error when I try to do something like this: char szHexData[ ] = response1.c_str();

Comment: Skip the array. Just pass `response1.c_str()` directly to `WriteFile`.

Comment: It works! But I'd like to store my string to a char[] or byte[]. Is this possible?

Comment: `std::string` already contains an array, you just need to access it through `c_str()` or `data()`. Get its size using `size()`.

Comment: @TheCodingBook It's possible but usually undesirable.

Comment: Oh, then I simply do something like strcpy( szHexData, sFileData.data( ) ); ? That easy?

Comment: First you have to create a dynamic array and then do the copy (using `std::copy()` rather than `std::strcpy()`). But dynamic arrays don't contain size information so you have to store that somewhere as well. That being so you may as well create a class to store both the array and its size together. But when you have done that you have something like a `std::string`class but less functional and probably full of bugs.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you feel you specifically _need_ the array?

Comment: @JustinTime as I said, I'd like to download a file and store the file into a BYTE buffer[] so to speak. Reason for this is that I'm about to inject the bytes into my other application so I can use those bytes. And yes, it has to be injected to my other application cuz I want 2 seperate things. It's kinda like seperate updater work but just with bytes injection. This is why I need that so badly .. I'd really appreciate anything useful which can help me out to transfer a file content (inc. headers, dos etc.) into a byte array.

Comment: c_str() gets a const char * that is the C representation of the string. You need it for interfacing with string functions that don't happen to use C++'s specific string representation, essentially anything not written in C++. To get rid of the constness, call strdup(), and you must then free the buffer, or strcpy() into your own buffer.

Comment: I literally fixed everything. filestream, std::string to BYTE[] and injecting bytes into my other app. I now can call functions which I injected from app A in app B :) thank you all!

Comment: @TheCodingBook Ah.  Glad you got it working.